# The solution of the following polynomial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve the following equation:

$$\frac{bc}{2}t^{4}-bct^{3}+\frac{a}{b^{2}}t^{2}-2\frac{a}{b^{2}}t+\frac{a}{b^{2}}=0$$

Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure it is entered correctly?

Comment: @Shard Yes, it is correct

Comment: There is a formula for solving 4th degree equations. It is too long to write here, but you should have no difficulty finding it in books on Theory of Equations, or by a websearch for "quartic formula".

Comment: While there is a formula, it so long and complicated that I would never expect it to be used for any (homework), even using it to solve the case $a=b=c=1$ is a headache and gives a horrible answer, which is why I wondered if the equation was entered correctly. Is this literally a homework question by itself? Or is this equation the result of some previous working which might be possibly be incorrect? There are a couple of very small changes to the question which would suddenly make it much easier to solve.

Comment: Solve for which variable? Are you sure there isn't more to it?

Comment: @DoctorGrizz: Thank you, The variable t.